# Show that this gluing of spaces produces the circle.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

I'm trying to understand this example here:

[Help understanding CW-complex construction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458975/help-understanding-cw-complex-construction/458980)

So basically, we consider a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and we consider the set

$$X^1 := \{x_0\} \sqcup [0,1]/\sim$$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation identifying $0 \sim 1 \sim x_0$.

It is claimed that $X^1$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$, but I can't see why this is true.

So, let me be really formal about my understanding. We have a disjoint union, so we will give labels.

$$\{x_0\} \sqcup [0,1] := \{(x_0,1)\} \cup \{(y,2): y \in [0,1]\}$$

and then I guess we identify $(x_0,1) \sim (0,2) \sim (1,2)$. How does this give something homeomorphic to $S^1$?

I guess I will need to view $S^1$ as the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ where $x \sim y \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and pick a representative $x \in [0,1[$ of $S^1$ and define

$$\psi: S^1 \to X^1: [x] \mapsto  \{(x,2)\}$$

I can see this is a bijection. How can I show that this is continuous? Since $S^1$ is compact, it will follow that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: $0$, $1$ and $x_0$ become the _same_ point in the quotient space. Imagine the unit interval as a piece of string and then glue its ends together. What do you get?

Comment: @BenSteffan Thanks for your comment. I do see the intuition, but I have trouble formalising it. Is the map I wrote down the good one to show it is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I would personally view $S^1$ as the set of all complex numbers with magnitude one and then use the map $e^{2 \pi i t} \mapsto t$, with $t$ in $[0, 1)$.

Comment: @Ben Steffan. How would you show that this is continuous?

Comment: You apply the universal property of the quotient.

Comment: @BenSteffan That does not quite work. I need my map to be in the other direction for that? I can see that a map $f: X^1 \to Z$ is continuous iff $f \circ \pi$ is continuous where $\pi$ is the canonical projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you be "really formal" in a somewhat different sense: let $X^1 = \{-1\} \cup [0,1]$ with equivalence relation $-1 \sim 0 \sim 1$.

Second, I would suggest that you define a map which goes straight from $X^1$ to $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$, without passing through the intermediate step of viewing $S^1$ as the quotient $\mathbb R / \sim$. So, just define
$$f : X^1 \to S^1
$$
by $f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2 \pi t))$.

Now use a simple theorem from topology:

> If $f : Y \to Z$ is a continuous, surjective function from a compact space $Y$ to a Hausdorff space $Z$, and if $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $Y$ defined by $y_1 \sim y_2$ if and only if $f(y_1)=f(y_2)$, and if $Y / \sim$ is the quotient space of this equivalence relation, and if $F : Y /\!\sim \, \to Z$ is the induced function defined by $F[y]=f(y)$, then $F$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Mosher. Any idea how I could formally show that your map f is continuous?

Comment: Also, I believe in the statement you are quoting you don't need Hausdorff and compactness assumptions.

Comment: If you assume that $f$ is a final map.

Comment: I proved that $f$ is continuous in the following way: using the universal properties of final sinks (i.e. of quotient and disjoint union), we see that the map $f$ you defined is continuous iff the maps $f \circ \pi \circ i_1, f \circ \pi\circ i_2$ are continuous where $\pi$ is the canonical projection sending an element to its equivalence class and where $i_1, i_2$ are the canonical injections of a factor into the disjoint union. The map $f \circ \pi \circ i_1: \{x_0\} \to S^1$ is clearly continuous as the domain is discrete, the map $f: \circ \pi \circ i_2: [0,1] \to S^1$

Comment: sending $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2 \pi t)$ is continuous by elementary calculus, and we deduce that the map you wrote down is continuous. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, by ordinary calculus. What the extra hypotheses are needed for is to conclude that the inverse function is continuous.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Mosher. So the argument with reducing to the continuity of the two associated maps is correct?